# How do you plot a relation between hardness and strain

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials, stresses, material-science

How do I plot the relation between hardness of a material and compressive strain knowing the stress-strain curve and indentation size in Brinell's hardness test

Comment: I suggest reading this wiki article as an introduction. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardness

Comment: take materials and plot hardness versus yield strength.  I'm not aware of hardness being a function of strain, other than strain hardening.